# OOP selecting data mysql

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo, mysqli

I'm new to OOP and just trying to migrate from mysql_, but I'm running into some issues while migrating.

```
$konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', root, root);$hasil = $konek->query("SELECT * FROM `tabel`");
while ($data = $hasil->fetch_object()) {
echo '<td>'.$data->something.'</td>';}
```

It doesn't work or show an error, but when I replace the first line with `mysqli` it works:

```
konek = new mysqli('localhost','root','root','mydatabase');
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I suspect you aren't getting errors because: 1) You haven't configured PHP in general to do so. 2) You don't have any PDO specific error checking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume in your code, it is coded as string: (or is `root` defined?)

```
$konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', root, root);
```

Clearly, in your example, if it's a type change it to:

```
$konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
```

Refactor your code into this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

try {
    $konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$hasil = $konek->query("SELECT * FROM `tabel`");
echo '<table>';
while ($row = $hasil->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row->column_name . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: thanks for the help , now every error is displayed , i use MAMP and i think error is hidden by default

Comment: @user3181160 yes even in other environment, its usually off as default you really have to set it first, glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

1)User name and password should be quoted string

2) use try catch

3) use prepare and execute the query

4) then fetch

try like this:

```
try {
    $konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', 'root', 'root');
    $konek->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

try {
    $hasil = $konek->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tabel`");
    $hasil->execute();
    while ($data = $hasil->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    echo '<td>'.$data->something.'</td>';
    }

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
        die( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: try {
    $konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=jwcrm2', 'root', 'root');
    $konek->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

try{}
$hasil = $konek->query("SELECT * FROM `kontak`");
 while ($data = $hasil->fetch_object()) {
 echo '<td>'.$data->nomer.'</td>';
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    die( 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

Comment: Ok thanks this is works :) , i just try to edit the tabel that doesnt exist but it doesnt show error , is it supposed to be that way ?

Answer (score -1):

Please provide an error message it echoes.

MY best guess:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Try replacing

```
while ($data = $hasil->fetch_object()) {
echo '<td>'.$data->something.'</td>';}
```

with

```
while ($data = $hasil->fetchAll()) {
echo '<td>'.$data->something.'</td>';}
```

Comment: Please try putting error_reporting into E_ALL mode http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Also please do var_dump on the $data variable and put the error here.